# Models in Perfect (Server-Side Swift) and StORM

Tags: apache-storm, perfect, server-side-swift

I have some question about modeling in Perfect and using StORM (MySQL-StORM in my case).
Assume we have models named `User` and `Note` with these simple rules:

- Users have `id, firstName, lastName, age(optional)`
- Notes have `id, title, content`
- Users could have `Zero or more` notes.
- Every note belongs to `One` user.

My questions are:

1. What data-types does StORM support?
2. How can I set `age` property `null-able` in database?
3. How can I create relation between `User` and `Note`?

something like this:

```
class User {
    var id: UUID
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var age: String? //this could be NULL-able, 

    var notes: [Note] //users notes
}

class Note {
    var id: UUID
    var title: String
    var content: String

    var owner: User //owner of the note
}
```

How can I implement this, using Perfect (Server-Side Swift) and MySQL-StORM?